# How to quit a C++ program?

Tags: c++, exit-code

How do I quit a C++ program. Which function is called to end a program and which values does the method take?

To clarify I want to exit a C++ program from within my code. And I may want to exit the program outside of the `main` function of this program.

Comment: Although it is unusual to close an older question as a duplicate of a more recent one, the new question has better answers, and contradicts (or, at least, gives a more complete and nuanced answer that largely contradicts) the recommendation here, and with cogent reasons.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938/should-i-flag-a-question-as-duplicate-if-it-has-received-better-answers