# Unable to write a data file,despite having no errors

Tags: c++, borland-c++

For my school project, i am creating a game. For save game features, I am using a `.DAT` binary file to read and write the data. When I enter the necessary details, the file doesn't have any data stored in it after exiting the program.

```cpp
void save_game()
{
    savegame sg;

    fstream x("savegame.dat", ios::out|ios::binary);
    char pn[25];

    sg.points = point;

    sg.lives = count;

    clrscr();

    settextstyle(TRIPLEX_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 3);

    outtextxy(50, 50, "ENTER YOUR NAME,PLAYA!");

    cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";

    gets(pn);

    strcpy(sg.pname, pn);

    x.write((char*)&sg, sizeof(sg));

    quitgame();
}
```

When I open the `.DAT` file, I expect to have some data stored in it. However, the file remains empty.

Answer (score 4):

You've not provided a [compilable verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so I can only use my crystal ball to help you. In the crystal ball I see that `quitgame()` calls `exit()`, in which case the destructor of your `x` doesn't get called, so the file isn't closed nor flushed to disk. Thus it remains empty.

See also a related question and links therein: [Why is using exit() considered bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25141737/673852)

Comment: You got one of the useful crystal balls, then. Mine just glows with a red fire and hisses, "I see you."