# Correctly exit forked process in C++

Tags: c++, fork, destructor, exit, double-free

Reading the answer to [How to end C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250934/how-to-end-c-code), I learned that calling `exit` from C++ code is bad. But what if I have forked a child process which must end *somewhere* and is so deep down the call stack that passing down its exit code to main would be impossible?

I found a few alternatives how to do that -- admittedly, this has become a bit lengthy, but bear with me:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <cstdlib>

#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

thread_local char const* thread_id{"main"};

struct DtorTest {
    std::string where{};
     DtorTest(void) = default;
     DtorTest(std::string _where) : where{std::move(_where)} {}
    ~DtorTest(void) {
        std::cerr << __func__ << " in " << thread_id << ", origin " << where << std::endl;
    }
};

std::unique_ptr< DtorTest > freeatexit{nullptr};

pid_t
fork_this(pid_t (*fork_option)(void))
{
    DtorTest test(__func__);
    return fork_option();
}

pid_t
fork_option0(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()))
        return pid;
    thread_id = "child";
    DtorTest test(__func__);
    std::exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

pid_t
fork_option1(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()))
        return pid;
    thread_id = "child";
    DtorTest test(__func__);
    std::_Exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

pid_t
fork_option2(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()))
        return pid;
    {
    thread_id = "child";
    DtorTest test(__func__);
    }
    std::_Exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

pid_t
fork_option3(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()))
        return pid;
    thread_id = "child";
    DtorTest test(__func__);
    throw std::exception();
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int status;
    const int option = (argc > 1) ? std::stoi(argv[1]) : 0;
    pid_t pid;
    freeatexit = std::unique_ptr< DtorTest >(new DtorTest(__func__));


    switch (option) {
      case 0:
        pid = fork_this(fork_option0);
        break;
      case 1:
        pid = fork_this(fork_option1);
        break;
      case 2:
        pid = fork_this(fork_option2);
        break;
      case 3:
        try {
            pid = fork_this(fork_option3);
        } catch (std::exception) {
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
        break;
      case 4:
        try {
            pid = fork_this(fork_option3);
        } catch (std::exception) {
            std::_Exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        break;
      default:
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

    return status;
}
```

## Option 0

Possibly the worst:

```
./a.out 0
~DtorTest in main, origin fork_this
~DtorTest in child, origin main
~DtorTest in main, origin main
```

The problem is, that the destructor of `test` in `fork_option0` is not called, because [std::exit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) simply ignores any object with automatic storage. Worse, the `unique_ptr` destructor is called *twice*.

## Option 1

```
./a.out 1
~DtorTest in main, origin fork_this
~DtorTest in main, origin main
```

Same problem with the destructor in `fork_option1` because [std::_Exit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/_Exit) ignores automatic storage as well. At least the `unique_ptr` destructor is called only once.

## Option 2

This seems to work, the destructors are called correctly.

```
./a.out 2
~DtorTest in main, origin fork_this
~DtorTest in child, origin fork_option2
~DtorTest in main, origin main
```

## Option 3

This is the nearest approximation to the *return from main* advice, however it has several problems:

```
./a.out 3
~DtorTest in main, origin fork_this
~DtorTest in child, origin fork_option3
~DtorTest in child, origin fork_this
~DtorTest in child, origin main
~DtorTest in main, origin main
```

Although the destructors in `fork_option3` are correctly invoked, **two** double frees happen. First the `unique_ptr`, second the object in `fork_this`.

## Option 4

```
./a.out 4
~DtorTest in main, origin fork_this
~DtorTest in child, origin fork_option3
~DtorTest in child, origin fork_this
~DtorTest in main, origin main
```

Slightly better than option three, because the double free of the `unique_ptr` is gone. However the objects in `fork_this` are still double free'd.

**So what is the proper way to exit/end a child process?**

From the above experiments it would seem that option2 works best. However, I might have missed other problems with `std::_Exit` (see [How to end C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250934/how-to-end-c-code))

Comment: Why would you not simply call `return`?

Comment: @Galik The child's work is done, it should cease to exist.

Comment: The child's work is not done if the destructors of its automatic variables have not been called.

Comment: @Galik I can agree with that. However, I don't want the child process to continue in main.

Comment: You might care to review [How to end C++ code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250934) but you may have a different scenario from what's assumed there, and you may need to look at one or more of the cross-referenced questions to suit your situation.

Comment: I see it is old, but just a note here: there is no `double free` in the code. Each process has its own address space, and `free`s the data inside that. Each of those two instance's are `free`d once. Only have to be careful with resources other than memory.

Answer (score 0):

This is the traditional pattern of `fork`.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

struct DtorTest {
    ~DtorTest(void) { std::cout << "d'tor never runs\n"; }
};

int
child(void)
{
    // only child
    DtorTest dtortest;  // D'tor never runs
    std::ofstream fout("inchild.txt");  // file not flushed
    fout << "this is in the child\n";
    return 0;
}

int
main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()))
      int status;
      waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
      return status;
   } else {
      return child();
   }
}
```

Don't use `extern "C"` for the system include files. If you need that, then you must be using an ancient compiler, and all bets are off.

Comment: My example is a simplified version. The fork happens deeper in the call stack such that returning the exit code to main is not an option.

Comment: Please have a look at option 3 & 4 from my updated post. It shows that your proposed solution doesn't work.