# Is there a way to end a program within a void function?

Tags: c++

I want to know if you can end a *program* from within a **void function**. I know that with using `void()`, you can't just do `return 0`, so what is there that would allow me to end my program early?

Here is some code to help you understand my situation:

```
void checkInput(int a) {
    if (a is negative) {
        cout << "Your number can't be negative" << endl;
        // exit program
    }
    else {
        // move on to calculate square root function
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do here is simulate a problem where a function `checkInput()` will check and see if a number is negative before it goes onto the next function, which actually performs the square root of the number, so I want to make sure it's not negative. If it is negative, I want to exit out of the program. This is just an example program.

Answer (score 3):

You could use C's [`exit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/):

```
void checkInput(int a) {
  if (a is negative) {
    cout << "Your number can't be negative" << endl;
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  } else {
    // move on to calculate square root function
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works fantastically!

Answer (score 2):

For an early return from the function

```
return;
```

For an [early terminate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) of the process (abnormal termination)

```
std::terminate();
```

For an [early exit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) ("normal" termination)

```
std::exit(0); // or some other error code
```

Ultimately, it may be better to define a flow control that allows the program to end after `main` has completed.

Comment: `std::terminate()` just calls `std::abort()` by default.  Why the extra layer of indirection?

Comment: Also, this means that static destructors won't get called.  This could be very surprising.

Comment: @DietrichEpp. Terminate has additional hooks, such as [`set_terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate) etc., but yes, the default will eventually call `abort`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp. Sure, but it sounds like the OP is looking for an abnormal exit based on an error condition.

Comment: There could still be reasons why you'd want destructors to run.  The first answer here sums it up well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250934/how-to-end-c-code/30251056#30251056

Comment: @DietrichEpp. Agreed. That is a nice answer. In the end you need to decide what the error is and how "bad" it is. I still think the best is to define a flow that allows exit out of `main`. There are no surprises then.

Answer (score 0):

One keyword and a semicolon:

```
return;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `exit` function. It takes a single argument, which is the return value for the program that will be returned to the shell. This function is included from `<stdlib.h>`

However, the better way would be to add a return value to `checkInput` since using a `exit` in the middle of a function is spaghetti code.

Comment: The comment about spaghetti code is not really appropriate.  If you are writing a command-line batch program, the best way to handle an error is often to just print a message and `exit(1)`.

Comment: I agree if the `exit` calls are in the same scope/function, then it would be fine to call `exit` directly instead of skipping to the end of the function. But having an `exit` call in very function that might fail is exactly spaghetti code.