# Getting a "possibly lost" memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Getting a Memory leak. `valgrind` says it might be somewhere in here. Any help would be really appreciated. Somewhere maybe around `enter relevant sort`....`where algorithm is one of bubble, sort2, or sort 3`

```
void usageAbort(string progname, string message)
{
    cerr << message << endl
         << "Usage:  " << progname << " algorithm" << endl
         << "     where algorithm is one of "
         << "bubble, sort2, or sort3"
         << endl;
    exit(1);
}

/***************************************************************************/
/**                                                                       **/
/***************************************************************************/


string algorithmFromCommandLine(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 

    string program = argv[0];
    string algorithm = argv[1];
    if(argc!=2){
        usageAbort(program, "enter proper argument count");
    } 

    if((algorithm == "bubblesort") or (algorithm == "quicksort") or
        (algorithm== "insertionsort")){
            return algorithm;
    }
    else{
        usageAbort(program,"enter relevant sort");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Are there some static pointers somewhere in your code? I don't see any memleak in this piece of your code.

Comment: Does changing parameters of `usageAbort()` to `const char*` works?  I don't see needs of using string there.  I guess valgrid assume there is possible leak because the memory in the temp `string` (in parameter) have no chance to be properly freed (as you are using `exit()` in the method)

Comment: Valgrind often shows some "unfreed" memory. The way to test it is easy - create a program with basic libraries included and with empty main. Compile it -> run it with valgrind and you can see, how much unfreed memory you can have, without feeling bad about it :)

Comment: Is the memory usage really growing out of control  ? is it slowing down ? is it crashing ? if the answers are no, no, no I think you could use your time in a more profitable way.

Answer (score 1):

`exit()` doesn't invoke the destructors of automatic objects, in particular function arguments. So the memory used by `progname` and `message` (and probably by other variables in your code) isn't deleted properly. In general using `exit()` isn't a good idea, see [How to end C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30250934/3959454).