# Quit the whole program early in C?

Tags: c, terminate

Generally say I have some functions `step1` `step2` ... and they are called successively:

```
int main()
{
  ...
  step1();  // something wrong detected and need to break out of the whole program
  step2();
  step3();
  ...
}
```

How can I break out from `step1` and skip all the rest of code to terminate `main()` function?

Currently I can only think of setting a global variable like `bool isErr` as a flag so that

```
step1();  // error detected and isErr is set to 1 inside step1()
if (isErr)
  return;
step2();
...
```

Are there better or more 'canonical' approaches?

BTW I've heard that `goto` is bad so I discard it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to quit a C++ program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116493/how-to-quit-a-c-program)

Comment: If the problem is because of some data flow that you would like the user to be able to inspect, `std::abort()` may be a good idea, since it exits the process with a signal and may cause the host to create a core dump (making the situation debuggable in multiple ways).

Comment: C is not C++ is not C! Pick one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to check return value of your `step1()` function and if it is error, just use for example `return 1` in `main`. Using `return` (with appropriate status code) from `main` to finish the program is the preferred way in C++.

Other option is `exit`. The point is you can call it anywhere in the code. However, in C++ `exit` is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250934/how-to-end-c-code) recommended that much. Regarding C, there is a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501142/should-we-use-exit-in-c) which discusses whether using `exit` in C is a good idea or not.

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
exit(1);
```

The number indicates the exit status. 0 is no failure, everything larger then 0 indicates an error.

Comment: The only portable return values in C are `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` (but not `1`).

Comment: EXIT_FAILURE is defined as 1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `exit()` function to terminate the process at any point during `step1()`, `step2()`... anywhere actually.

Answer (score 1):

[`exit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/) will terminate the program from wherever you are, but in most cases this is a bad idea, checking the return value of a function and handling (e.g. exit in your case) is a cleaner way to do it (no need for globals)